# Invoicing system with product number database?

Tags: invoicing, product-management

I'm looking for some software with two main features:

- invoice generation
- product lists with part numbers and prices.

The goal is to minimize time spent on manual data entry, as these invoices typically have many line items. The idea is that the user can punch in a series of part numbers (and QTY), and the software will automatically populate the description, denomination, unit price, and total price fields. This system needs to store multiple lists of items with the above fields.

Is there an off-the-shelf solution that will meet these needs?

Comment: Free? What is your budget? Are cloud solutions OK, or do you want to run it on your own computers/server?

Comment: If on your own machine: what are the OS requirements? What kind of GUI to access it: local clients, web clients? Where should the data be stored to, and what format? Plus, as you certainly want to read the stored data for further processing: any requirements concerning that part? Interfaces? APIs? Please check [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and see if you can [edit] your question to incorporate some of the suggestions. It will highly improve your chances to good answers!